# __LINE__ поломался

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, макросы

Есть такая штука:

```
#define V(type, name) vector<type> name
#define VV_make(type, name, dim1, dim2, value, line) V(type, init##line)(dim2, value); V(vector<type>, name)(dim1, init##line)
#define VV(type, name, dim1, dim2, value) VV_make(type, name, dim1, dim2, value, __LINE__)
```

При таком обращении к ней:

```
VV(int, arr, 30, 50, 7);
```

Она разворачивается в это:

```
vector<int> init__LINE__(50, 7);
vector<vector<int>> arr(30, init__LINE__);
```

А я хочу это:

```
vector<int> init25(50, 7);
vector<vector<int>> arr(30, init25);
```

ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь (а может, и ошибаюсь...) - то попробуйте так:

```
#define V(type, name) vector<type> name
#define VAL(i,x) i##x
#define VV_make(type, name, dim1, dim2, value, line) V(type, VAL(init,line))(dim2, value); V(vector<type>, name)(dim1, VAL(init,line))
#define VV(type, name, dim1, dim2, value) VV_make(type, name, dim1, dim2, value, __LINE__)
```

В VC++ вроде работает...

Comment: в clion тоже. странно как-то. это костыль языка такой?

Comment: Да просто такой вариант - только еще хуже :) - используется при стрингификации :) - ну, переводе в строку, вот я его и применил. Потому и не очень в ответе был уверен.